# Error: invalid format (line 5) entry: "cn=schema,config" when trying to add attributypes and objectclasses

Tags: ubuntu, ldap, openldap, ubuntu-16.04, ilo

I'm trying to implement HP iLO authentication via openLDAP, for implementing this authentication I need to add an attributetype memberof and 2 objectclasses  (memberof and user) on the openldapserver. I'm trying to push these elements via the ldapmodify command, but I'm always getting the following error:

```
ldapmodify: invalid format (line 6) entry: "cn=schema,config"
```

This is the ldapmodify command that I use:

```
sudo ldapmodify -H ldapi:// -Y EXTERNAL -D "cn=schema,cn=config" -f ilo.schema
```

In the `ilo.schema` file my attributype and objectclasses are defined:

```
dn: cn=schema,cn=config
objectClass: olcSchemaConfig
changetype: modify
add: olcAttributeTypes
olcAttributeTypes: ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.15959.9.1.1 NAME 'memberOf'
DESC 'Group which user belongs to'
EQUALITY distinguishedNameMatch
SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.12
USAGE userApplications )
-
add: olcObjectClasses
olcObjectClasses: ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.15959.9.2.1 NAME 'memberOf'
DESC 'Required by Integrated Lights-Out for OpenLDAP '
SUP top
AUXILIARY
MUST memberOf )
-
add: olcObjectClasses
olcObjectClasses: ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.15959.9.2.2 NAME 'user'
DESC 'Required by Integrated Lights-Out for OpenLDAP '
SUP top
AUXILIARY )
```

I also tried the following syntax (but I get the same error):

```
attributetype ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.15959.9.1.1
NAME 'memberOf'
DESC 'Group which user belongs to'
EQUALITY distinguishedNameMatch
SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.12 )

objectclass ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.15959.9.2.1
NAME 'memberOf'
SUP top AUXILIARY
DESC 'Required by Integrated Lights-Out for OpenLDAP '
MUST ( memberOf )
)

objectclass ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.15959.9.2.2
NAME 'user'
SUP top AUXILIARY
DESC 'Required by Integrated Lights-Out for OpenLDAP '
)
```

I think it's something about my syntax in the ilo.schema file but I don't see it at all.

Can anybody help me with this? Thanks in advance.

PS The openldap server is running on Ibuntu server 16.04, and the HP iLO version is iLO 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax of your ldif is wrong, you'd need to use line wrapping. However, so is your approach.
You should be using the `uid` attribute from OpenLDAP's base schema (no need to modify anything, it's already included), `groupOfNames` from `core` schema and `slapo-memberof` to provide `memberOf`.